# Context-sensitive newline macro

Tags: macros, line-breaking, line-spacing

I'd like to write a new command `putOnNewLine` such that `\putOnNewLine{ABC}` puts ABC on a new line, with exactly one line's vertical space separating it from what has gone before.

It must also respect the boundaries of any environment it is inside.  For example, if I have a `\putOnNewLine` at the start of an environment (say at the start of a proof following a theorem) then I don't want a new line in that case.

So I suppose I am also looking for some sort of logic that is sensitive to the context in which the command appears.

Answer (score 3):

You could use something like

```
\newcommand{\putOnNewLine}[1]{\par\vspace{\baselineskip}#1}
```

or

```
\newcommand{\putOnNewLine}[1]{\newline~\newline#1}
```

Although it depends a bit on the purpose you would like to use this for.

Comment: Thanks for this.  The only problem with it is that if I have a `\putOnNewLine` at the start of an environment (say at the start of a proof following a theorem) then I don't want a new line in that case.

Comment: I suppose I am looking for some sort of logic that is sensitive to the context in which the command appears.

Comment: @Alex you should probably mention that in your question.

Comment: I have edited the question.